# How in bachInsert to compare the data with the fields?

Tags: yii2

```
public static  $columnsInsert =
    [
        'id',
        'customer_id',
        'summary',
        'description',
        'color',
        'favourite',
        'update_at',
        'create_at',
        'personEmail'
    ];


$sql = $db->queryBuilder->batchInsert(self::$table, self::$columnsInsert, $data);
```

From the client, there are arrays of rows with the same keys in the string. But why then the data is not matched with the fields in the query. Is it really necessary to select the order under the data from the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you  have the columns for insert in sequence as below

```
  public static  $columnsInsert =
      [
          'id',
          'customer_id',
          'summary',
          'description',
          'color',
          'favourite',
          'update_at',
          'create_at',
          'personEmail'
      ];
```

then your $data should have the same sequnce  ..

```
    $data =
      [
         [
          value_for_id,
          value_for_idfor_customer_id,
          value_for_summary  ,
          value_for_description,
          value_for_color,
          value_for_favourite,
          value_for_update_at,
          value_for_create_at,
          balue_personEmail
        ], 
        [
          value_for_id,
          value_for_idfor_customer_id,
          value_for_summary  ,
          value_for_description,
          value_for_color,
          value_for_favourite,
          value_for_update_at,
          value_for_create_at,
          balue_personEmail
        ], 
      ];

  so you should adapt your columns sequence or your data sequence for a correct match
```

pratically the $columnInsert is the part used  in the column declaaration part of the insert

```
INSERT  INTO your_table ('id',  'customer_id','summary','description',
    'color','favourite','update_at','create_at','personEmail')
```

and the data is for the values

```
VALUES (value_for_id, value_for_id, for_customer_id,  value_for_summary, 
  value_for_description, value_for_color,  value_for_favourite, 
  value_for_update_at,  value_for_create_at,  balue_personEmail), 
      (value_for_id, value_for_id, for_customer_id,  value_for_summary, 
  value_for_description, value_for_color,  value_for_favourite,
  value_for_update_at,  value_for_create_at,  balue_personEmail), 
       (value_for_id, value_for_id, for_customer_id,  value_for_summary  ,
  value_for_description, value_for_color,  value_for_favourite, 
  value_for_update_at,  value_for_create_at,  balue_personEmail),
  ........
```

as you can see the two part have the same sequence

Comment: And if in data there will be keys similar but other order. Will not work ?

Comment: same order  ..  so you should adapt or you data order or your column order  .. as in a SQL batch insert ..

Comment: $sql = $db->queryBuilder->batchInsert(self::$table, arrow_keys($data[0]), $data);

Comment: ... @Pasha   . arrow_keys ??? ..  array_key is better .give you the columns name you need ..  .and in the same order as you need .is a very good suggestion. this don't change the issue that column name and value must be in the same  order  . ..